# CSS3 Transition, hover to trigger animation on child element not working

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I would like my list item to trigger a css3 transition on its child item `.pusher` when hovered over.
I am used to doing this in JS and not css3 transitions, after reading some other SO questions I thought I understood how to do it, but it's not working correctly:

```css
#sidebar ul {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#sidebar ul li {
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4a4a4a;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: max-width 0.5s ease;
    transition: max-width 0.5s ease;
}
#sidebar ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 5;
    position: relative;
}
#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#sidebar ul li:hover > .pusher {
    max-width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #383838;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
#sidebar ul li:first-child {
    border-top: 1px solid #4a4a4a;
}
```

Pusher is actually being appended to li, with JS, but I don't think this should cause an issue? (edit: this does not appear to be the issue)

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8KpQW/

Comment: Make a fiddle for your problem

Comment: You could try a test example with the `.pusher` element hard coded in the `li` just to see if it works or not.

Comment: just tried that now in a fiddle, @jwatts1980 unfortunately it didn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/8KpQW/

Comment: What is `.pusher` supposed to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't defined a width for `.pusher` merely a `max-width` so it doesn't know how wide it is supposed to be.

Try this

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8KpQW/6/)

**CSS extract**

```css
.pusher {
    width:0;
    transition:width 0.5s ease;
}

#sidebar ul li:hover .pusher {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #383838;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: there doesn't appear to be any easing/transition/animation?

Comment: for 'inner' :hover :-)

Answer (score 0):

The code below fixed the issue for me :

```
 #sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 74px;
  background: #303030;
  color: #fff;
}
#sidebar ul {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#sidebar ul li {
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4a4a4a;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#sidebar ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
}
#sidebar ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#sidebar ul li .pusher {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  background: #383838;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
#sidebar ul li:hover > .pusher {
  width: 100%;
}
```

the transition property needs to be applied to the actual element to be animated, not the hover trigger element. hover, merely needs to contain the property value that the animation will end on.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8KpQW/3/